# Unable to load CryptoJS library in my application which is not an open source

Tags: javascript, encryption, aes, cryptojs

I need to use CryptoJS for JavaScript encryption and decryption in my application (QIK technology).

When I try to do that, the CryptoJS libraries fail to load with the following message:

```
"javascript failure error and the CryptoJS  is undefined"
```

I have attached the error screen shot which I am getting here.

The test example I am trying to do is given below as Fiddle 1 and Fiddle 2. Do I need to do any external setup to access CryptoJS to my application?

[image]

My fiddles: [Fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/1qgzk9j8/) and [Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/6gunq2nx/).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include code that you tried in the question itself. And add every other detail. You can then delete your comments.

Comment: Are you trying to load Javascript code from Java code ?

Comment: not ofcourse...as it is not an open source we used to include the libraries in that manner.SO I just tried over and commented(PFA)

Answer (score 1):

There is not special setup. Just include the library as per the documentation :

- [The Cipher Output](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#The_Cipher_Output)
- [AES](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#AES)

I've updated your fiddle with a working example (i've moved your Js code from the HTML panel to the javascript one and added the jQuery library to display the results) :
[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1qgzk9j8/4/)

HTML :

```
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/aes.js"></script>
```

Javascript

```
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Message", "Secret Passphrase");
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, "Secret Passphrase");
console.log(decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```

I've added a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/5H2mn8lFpkQvtqgwGlxg) as well, to show you the setup on a more realistic page :

Hope it helps !

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I've made some edits. The question is not very good indeed, but my answer is still better than RTFM ;)

Comment: I have attached screen shot of the error which I am getting in ma application.even if I try your code still it is showing the error when it reaches to CryptoJS. I am unable to recognize the issue.please try to help me on this..

Comment: @cl3m There is always the possibility that the OP rejects the edit. It was a good edit, but you could've also included the links to the fiddles from the comments (comments may be deleted at any time) or even included the "code" from the fiddle.